# Object wont move continiously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so im trying to move the object continuously when I press left click once. but ive tried and have no luck can anyone help me Thanks.

Here's my code

```
 public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed;
    private Vector2 moveDir;
    public Transform target;
    private void Awake()
    {
        moveDir = new Vector2(-8, 0);
        speed = 0.5f;

    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            transform.LookAt(target, Vector3.zero);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -45f);
            moveDir.x += speed;
            moveDir.y += speed;
            transform.position = new Vector2(moveDir.x, moveDir.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            transform.LookAt(target, Vector3.back);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -135f);
            moveDir.x += speed;
            moveDir.y -= speed;
            transform.position = new Vector2(moveDir.x, moveDir.y);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Im not sure you want to add speed to your movedir each frame, with 200fps for example in one second you could be moving 100 units every frame....  So do you want to click once and it remains moving or moving while the mouse is down?

Comment: i want to click once and it remains moving. @BugFinder

Comment: so use getmousebuttondown so its only the frame it was pressed on, and have it set how its moving, and then move it every frame at whatever speed was already set

Comment: @BugFinder how do I move it every frame. for some reason idk where to put Time.deltatime

Comment: move the move outside of any ifs, so it happens every frame..  and normally the move is multiplied by deltatime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        bool moveLeft = false;    


        void Update()
        {

            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
               moveLeft = true;
            }

            if(moveLeft)
            {
               //Your Movement Code
            }        

        }  
    }
```